# How to get postId from the argument $block when register_block_type()?

Tags: functions, theme-development, themes, block-editor

I'm trying to register custom block type in the file `functions.php` of my block theme:

```
function render_custom_block($attributes, $content, $block) {
    return $block->available_context['postId'];
}
add_action('init', function() {
    register_block_type('mytheme/custom-block',
        array(
            'render_callback' => 'render_custom_block'
        )
    );
});
```

But instead of getting `postId`, I always get `1`. When I try `print_r($block)`, I see the property `available_context` is protected and `context` is empty.

So how to get `postId` from the `$block` argument ?

Comment: What does `grt_the_ID()` function return?

Comment: @Tim Yes, `get_the_ID()` returns the expected ID. I found that out a few days ago, but just was not updated the question

Answer (score 2):

The `get_the_ID()` function will return the id of the current post in the loop.
If your block is used on a single post page or in a post loop (archive page) you can use this.